# I'm trying to create a letter with multiple strokes within a stroke.

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, stroke

[image: multiple strock letter]

I want to create something like the attached photo, but with other letters and shapes. does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: try drawing the first letter with the pen tool, then try playing with `Object > Path > Offset Path...`.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this drawing the two external shapes and then creating a blend, from `Object -> Blend -> Make` and edit the steps with `Object -> Blend -> Blend Options` and specify the steps.